# Portable way to put stdout in binary mode

Tags: c, linux, windows, io, portability

I'm writing C programs used as cgi's that generate and output gif images. They're used in HTML pages with tags of the form
`<img src="/cgi-bin/gifprogram.cgi?param=val&etc">`, where the query string params describe the image to be generated by the cgi.

C program cgi's invoked like this emit their output to stdout. And in this case the output's a gif image containing lots of binary (non-printable) bytes. That's already working fine on Unix/Linux. But Windows apparently requires a separate non-portable `_setmode(_fileno(stdout),_O_BINARY)` call (and some Windows-specific `#include`'s). Otherwise you get the usual cr/lf problem, i.e., every 0x0A is preceded by a spurious 0x0D. And that doesn't look good in a gif :(

Is there any portable way around this problem, using ANSI-standard C without any platform-specific syntax, and without a lot of `#ifdef` stuff to try to detect a Windows compile environment? Moreover, some Windows compilers apparently use `_setmode(_fileno(stdout),_O_BINARY)` while others use `setmode(fileno(stdout),O_BINARY)`, which I also have to try to detect.

**>>Edit<<** In reply to comments...

Thanks, guys. I'll apparently have to take some otherwise completely posix-compliant/portable programs, and goof around with them just for windows [n.b., JoNaThAn: really, no need to edit to capitalize that:), -- my personal writing style is intentionally grammatically loose].

Below is a first cut at some of the goofiness I'm considering introducing. Seems to work, as far as I can tell, using mingw. Is it sufficient, i.e., works for all-or-most other compilers? And is it necessary, i.e., any short-and-neat/quick-and-dirty way to accomplish the same thing with fewer/more-readable lines of code?

```
/* ---
 * windows-specific header info
 * ---------------------------- */
#ifndef WINDOWS                 /* -DWINDOWS not supplied by user */
  #if defined(_WINDOWS) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN32) \
  ||  defined(DJGPP)            /* try to recognize windows compilers */ \
  ||  defined(_USRDLL)          /* must be WINDOWS if compiling for DLL */
    #define WINDOWS             /* signal windows */
  #endif
#endif
#ifdef WINDOWS                  /* Windows opens stdout in char mode, and */
  #include <fcntl.h>            /* precedes every 0x0A with spurious 0x0D.*/
  #include <io.h>               /* So emitcache() issues a Win _setmode() */
                                /* call to put stdout in binary mode. */
  #if defined(_O_BINARY) && !defined(O_BINARY)  /* only have _O_BINARY */
    #define O_BINARY _O_BINARY  /* make O_BINARY available, etc... */
    #define setmode  _setmode
    #define fileno   _fileno
  #endif
  #if defined(_O_BINARY) || defined(O_BINARY)  /* setmode() now available */
    #define HAVE_SETMODE        /* so we'll use setmode() */
  #endif
  #if defined(_MSC_VER) && defined(_DEBUG) /* MS VC++ in debug mode */
    /* to show source file and line numbers where memory leaks occur... */
    #define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC   /* ...include this debug macro */
    #include <crtdbg.h>         /* and this debug library */
  #endif
  #define ISWINDOWS 1
#else
  #define ISWINDOWS 0
#endif
```

And the subsequent corresponding code to make sure stdout is in binary mode is

```
    #if ISWINDOWS                           /* compiling for win... */
      #ifdef HAVE_SETMODE                   /* try to use setmode()*/
        if ( setmode ( fileno (stdout), O_BINARY) /* to set stdout */
        == -1 ) /* handle error here*/ ;    /* to binary mode */
      #else                                 /* setmode not available */
        #if 1                               /* so try this...*/
          freopen ("CON", "wb", stdout);    /* freopen stdout binary */
        #else                               /* or maybe this... */
          stdout = fdopen (STDOUT_FILENO, "wb"); /*fdopen stdout binary*/
        #endif                              /* done */
      #endif                                /* " */
    #endif                                  /* " */
```

You'll note I'm trying to suggest setmode() alternatives. Though my alternative testing hasn't been successful, I've left the syntax in place for future reference, just in case some of it ultimately proves useful.

Comment: There is no portable way. You'll have to handle each platform separately.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Thanks for the quick  reply (I'd have been even more thankful for a positive reply:). I was kind of hoping for something like a cc -stdout=binary kind of switch, or something/anything like that. So some windows compilers (e.g., djgpp,mingw) might have that kind of -switch, while others not. Is that a possibility? You know of any compilers like that? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a compiler switch.

Comment: Even if there was a compiler switch, I doubt that it would do any good since the input and output handles for a process are set by the process that called it.  I suspect that the input and output streams are set to text mode even before your program runs.

Comment: The `setmode()` vs `_setmode()` issue arises because Microsoft thinks that POSIX functions pollute the user's name space, so it renames them all with a leading underscore.  It's ironic that it also renames `_setmode()` when `setmode()` isn't a POSIX function in the first place.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: depends what you mean; it is a function that is part of the POSIX-like emulation layer, completely useless if you aren't using  at least some of the other functions that *are* in POSIX.  But I don't think it matters; the excuse for making the change was that the functions in question weren't in the ISO C standard, so I guess they pretty much had to rename *all* such functions, regardless of whether they were related to POSIX or not. :-)

Comment: @JonTrauntvein: no, text or binary mode has nothing to do with the handles and can't be inherited, it is entirely local to the process.  (And only applies at all if you are using Microsoft's C runtime, or a third-party C runtime that behaves in the same way.)

Comment: Given that you want to avoid modifying the source code for specific platforms, but don't mind changing the build settings, it should be possible in principle to write a DLL that, when linked with a C program, causes `stdout` to be set to binary mode.  It would need to be built with the same compiler as the program, though.

Comment: @HarryJohnston (and others) Thanks for comments/suggestions. I've edited the question, illustrating (first cut of) windows-specific code to put stdout in binary mode. (I'll keep Harry's DLL suggestion in mind, but not going that route now.) Any comments/constructive-criticism (okay, or destructive:) about  that code? I'd love it if the fdopen() worked on windows. Then I could just put it inline, windows or not since it simply wouldn't affect unix, and that one line of code would get everything working portably/transparently.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Thanks again. As you originally suggested, I've edited question with first cut of windows-specific code. If you have a few minutes, please take a look (and see longer detailed comment to (at)HarryJohnston re the edits). Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for comments. I've edited question, adding code (and a longer explanatory comment to (at)HarryJohnston) trying to minimize necessary windows-specific changes.

Comment: Note that if your program is used as a CGI program, its standard output is almost certainly not the console. Thus, opening `CON:` is probably not correct; it will break any redirection created by the web server that launched the CGI program. Clearly, this code should be ghettoized into a function (`void setbinmode(FILE *fp)` perhaps) in a file that either does nothing on Unix or does some work on Windows.  Your program calls the function unconditionally. The compilation for the file containing that function is gruesome; the rest is clean.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, the freopen() didn't work; for that matter, neither did the fdopen(). I'm just trying everything I can think of that might affect the situation, and that might possibly work -- just to see what happens under windows. And like you say, I'll eventually encapsulate ("ghettoize" has such negative connotations:) what seems to be the "best of breed" solution. But for the time being, I'm just playing with the code to see what does what. Nowadays, it seems to me people are way too quick to refactor. Better to prototype with spaghetti code till you understand what you're doing.

Comment: `STDOUT_FILENO` is neither part of the C standard nor the de-facto Windows standard, so there's no obvious reason to expect that to work.  Something like `fdopen(fileno(stdout), "wb")` might work better.  My guess is that any compiler that accepts the "b" will also have a setmode(), but that *is* just a guess.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks, Harry. I'm not abundantly familiar with any of the standards, kind of just try to stay compliant with K&R2, and beyond that research portability of any non-K&R2 construct that I happen to need on an ad hoc, case-by-case basis. I'm especially unfamiliar with Windows, but STDOUT_FILENO's in unistd.h on linux, and I forget which Windows compiler I checked (probably mingw). Moreover, that STDOUT_FILENO occurs in an #if/#else construction at a point where I've checked for fileno() and _fileno(), and am worried neither's available. Don't really know what's most-likely-to-work.

Comment: FWIW, Microsoft's `setmode()` documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=msvc-140 has two examples explicitly using `_setmode( _fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY);` and `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);`, so I guess `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY);` should work as well. I found that while dealing with https://github.com/gphoto/gphoto2/issues/522 but there appears to be something else to consider.

Comment: @John Forkosh, I would expect  `freopen(NULL, "wb", stdout);` to work for you.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks, chux. Don't have a windows box immediately available, but will give it a try when I do. But on my linux box, man freopen says, in part: "The mode string can include the letter 'b' ... This is strictly for compatibility with C89 and has no effect; the 'b' is ignored on all POSIX  conforming  systems, including  Linux." So I'm a little skeptical, but I'm sure hoping that I'm wrong and you're right. As always, the computer will have the final word. (P.S. I'm surprised anybody's still looking at this six years after posting it.)